# WAR directory structure for Spring MVC JSP app?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am trying to follow Mkyong's excellent [Spring MVC/JSP tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/), however, it doesn't really explain what the final WAR's directory structure should look like.

I have taken his example and packaged a WAR with the following structure:

```
myapp.war/
    META-INF/
    WEB-INF/
        classes/
        lib/
        web.xml
        mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
```

However when I deploy the app to Tomcat I get the typical Tomcat 404 ("*The requested resource is not available.*") error, and in `catalina.out` I see:

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

Am I missing any files/resources, or have I packaged the WAR incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you referring to maps MVC Dispatcher to *.html files only. So need to access the application with URL similiar to /myapp/.htm that is when the dispatcher will kick in.